# How do you create a queue of threads in Delphi Xe2?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, queue, delphi-xe2

Have a case where the user may fire off a number of time-consuming jobs that need to be run in the order in which the user does them.

I have been looking at the class `TThreadedQueue` to store threads. Is that a good place to start? Or is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: If there is only one producer to input jobs, and the jobs must be invoked in order and a new job cannot start until the former is ready, the queue do not need to be thread safe. When a job is done, just fire an event in the main thread to start next job in the queue.

Comment: Why store threads. Store tasks. Have one thread to pull off new tasks one by one.

Answer (score -1):

below you can find an example of a WorkerThreadPool :

```
  {~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
  Twin_WorkerThreadPool = class;

  {~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
  Twin_WorkerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FProc: TProc;
    FProcReadySignal: Tevent;
    FProcFinishedSignal: Tevent;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ExecuteAndWaitProc(const AProc: TProc);
    property ProcFinishedSignal: Tevent read FProcFinishedSignal;
  end;

  {~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
  Twin_WorkerThreadPool = class(TObject)
  private
    fPool: TObjectList<Twin_WorkerThread>;
    fSignal: Tevent;
  public
    constructor Create(const aThreadCount: integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ExecuteAndWaitProc(const AProc: TProc);
    procedure Enqueue(const Value: Twin_WorkerThread);
    function Dequeue: Twin_WorkerThread;
  end;


{***********************************}
constructor Twin_WorkerThread.Create;
begin
  FProc := nil;
  FProcReadySignal := TEvent.Create(nil, false{ManualReset}, false, '');
  FProcFinishedSignal := TEvent.Create(nil, false{ManualReset}, false, '');
  inherited Create(False); // see http://www.gerixsoft.com/blog/delphi/fixing-symbol-resume-deprecated-warning-delphi-2010
end;

{***********************************}
destructor Twin_WorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate;
  FProcReadySignal.setevent;
  WaitFor;
  ALFreeAndNil(FProcReadySignal);
  ALFreeAndNil(FProcFinishedSignal);
  inherited;
end;

{**********************************}
procedure Twin_WorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  while True do begin
    try

      //wait the signal
      FProcReadySignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);

      //if terminated then exit
      if Terminated then Break;

      //execute fProc
      if assigned(FProc) then FProc();

      //signal the proc is finished
      FProcFinishedSignal.SetEvent;

    except
      //hide the exception
    end;
  end;
end;

{*****************************************************************}
procedure Twin_WorkerThread.ExecuteAndWaitProc(const AProc: TProc);
begin
  fProc := AProc;
  FProcFinishedSignal.ResetEvent;
  FProcReadySignal.SetEvent;
  FProcFinishedSignal.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  fProc := nil;
end;

{********************************************************************}
constructor Twin_WorkerThreadPool.Create(const aThreadCount: integer);
var i: integer;
begin
  fPool := TObjectList<Twin_WorkerThread>.create(false{aOwnObjects});
  fSignal := TEvent.Create(nil, true{ManualReset}, false, '');
  for I := 0 to aThreadCount - 1 do
    fPool.Add(Twin_WorkerThread.Create)
end;

{***************************************}
destructor Twin_WorkerThreadPool.Destroy;
var aWorkerThread: Twin_WorkerThread;
    i: integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to fPool.Count - 1 do begin
    aWorkerThread := fPool[i];
    fPool[i] := nil;
    ALFreeAndNil(aWorkerThread);
  end;
  ALFreeAndNil(fPool);
  ALFreeAndNil(fSignal);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

{*********************************************************************}
procedure Twin_WorkerThreadPool.ExecuteAndWaitProc(const AProc: TProc);
var aThread: Twin_WorkerThread;
begin
  aThread := Dequeue;
  try
    aThread.ExecuteAndWaitProc(aProc);
  finally
    Enqueue(aThread);
  end;
end;

{**********************************************************************}
procedure Twin_WorkerThreadPool.Enqueue(const Value: Twin_WorkerThread);
begin
  Tmonitor.Enter(fPool);
  try
    fPool.Add(Value);
    if fPool.Count = 1 then fSignal.SetEvent;
  finally
    Tmonitor.Exit(fPool);
  end;
end;

{********************************************************}
function Twin_WorkerThreadPool.Dequeue: Twin_WorkerThread;
begin
  Tmonitor.Enter(self); // << only one thread can process the code below
  try

    Tmonitor.Enter(fPool);
    try
      if Fpool.Count > 0 then begin
        result := fPool[Fpool.Count - 1];
        fPool.Delete(Fpool.Count - 1);
        exit;
      end;
      fSignal.ResetEvent;
    finally
      Tmonitor.Exit(fPool);
    end;

    while True do begin // << their is a bug on ios with tevent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884521/why-i-get-an-exception-argument-out-of-range
      fSignal.WaitFor(Infinite);
      Tmonitor.Enter(fPool);
      try
        if fPool.Count > 0 then begin
          result := fPool[Fpool.Count - 1];
          fPool.Delete(Fpool.Count - 1);
          exit;
        end
        else begin
          {$IFDEF DEBUG}
          ALLog('Twin_WorkerThreadPool.Dequeue', 'fSignal.ResetEvent didn''t work as expected!', TalLogType.Error);
          {$ENDIF}
        end;
      finally
        Tmonitor.Exit(fPool);
      end;
    end;

  finally
    Tmonitor.exit(self);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that code. I went to compile it and found a compiler error.
Where does ALFreeAndNil come from? What does it do?

Comment: aah sorry alfreeandnil come from alcinoe (you can found the code on the internet) ... alfreeandnil do exactly like freeandnil except that it's use dispose instead of free to avoid memory leak